# How to display data from my SQL database and show in a table as vertically

Tags: android, tablelayout

Currently I am working with a project to display database value in a table in Android vertically.I got the answer in horizontally, now I want it in vertically.

[image: my current output].

[image: I want it like this.].

Main Activity.java

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String data = "";
TableLayout tl;
TableRow tr;

TextView label;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);

    final GetDataFromDB getdb = new GetDataFromDB();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            data = getdb.getDataFromDB();
            System.out.println(data);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ArrayList<Users> users = parseJSON(data);
                    addData(users);
                }
            });

        }
    }).start();
}

public ArrayList<Users> parseJSON(String result) {
    ArrayList<Users> users = new ArrayList<Users>();
    try {
        JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(result);
        //JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray("users");

        JSONArray jArray = jsono.getJSONArray("agriculture1");
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Users user = new Users();
            user.setId(json_data.getInt("id"));
            user.setCrop(json_data.getString("crop"));
            user.setCategory(json_data.getString("category"));
            user.setSoil_texture(json_data.getString("soil_texture"));
            users.add(user);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    return users;
}

void addHeader(){
    /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
    tr = new TableRow(this);

    /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
    label = new TextView(this);
    label.setText("Crop");
    label.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    label.setPadding(30, 30, 30, 30);
    label.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
    //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
    Ll.addView(label,params);
    tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

    /** Creating Qty Button **/
    TextView place = new TextView(this);
    place.setText("Category");
    place.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    place.setPadding(30, 30, 30, 30);
    place.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
    //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
    Ll.addView(place,params);
    tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

    TextView soil = new TextView(this);
    soil.setText("Soil_Texture");
    soil.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    soil.setPadding(30, 30, 30, 30);
    soil.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
    //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
    Ll.addView(soil,params);
    tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow

    // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
    tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
public void addData(ArrayList<Users> users) {

    addHeader();

    for (Iterator i = users.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

        Users p = (Users) i.next();

        /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
        tr = new TableRow(this);

        /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
        label = new TextView(this);
        label.setText(p.getCrop());
        label.setId(p.getId());
        label.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        label.setPadding(10,10, 10, 10);
        label.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(label,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

        /** Creating Qty Button **/
        TextView place = new TextView(this);
        place.setText(p.getCategory());
        place.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        place.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        place.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(place,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

        TextView soil = new TextView(this);
        soil.setText(p.getCategory());
        soil.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        soil.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        soil.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(soil,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll);
        // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
}
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1">
    <TableLayout

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:id="@+id/maintable" >
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

Comment: what do you mean horizontally?

Comment: Sorry,I need it in vertically like the second image .

Comment: what the difference between two? looks similar. Why do you want horizontal? just get data and make listview item row with Linearlayout orientation horizontal

Comment: sir, Please check my second image, i want that output.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have to use 1 table? You can split your layout and use two tables one for "header" and one  for values.

You can split your layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="0dp"/>
  <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="0dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then add your tables inside the inner layouts.